# Aligned parent bottom relative layout hides recycler view

Tags: android, alignment

I've been searching everywhere for this issue.
I have aligned a LinearLayout to the bottom of the parent relative layout and also a RecyclerView, as same level child, the thing is that list does not detect the element on bottom and it scrolls till the end, so I can't see the last row of the list.
This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--some code-->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewComments"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:shadowColor="#000"
         android:shadowDx="-2"
         android:shadowRadius="8"
         android:shadowDy="-10"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--some code-->
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

set `android:layout_above` property to set the container of recyclerView avobe the footer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--some code-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/aLayout">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewComments"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:shadowColor="#000"
        android:shadowDx="-2"
        android:shadowRadius="8"
        android:shadowDy="-10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--some code-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: my bad... I was adding a layout_above on recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--some code-->
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewComments"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/bottomLinearLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:shadowColor="#000"
         android:shadowDx="-2"
         android:shadowRadius="8"
         android:shadowDy="-10"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--some code-->
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, your bottom LinearLayout overlaps the RecyclerView. By using `android:layout_above` on the parent layout of RecyclerView we can avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You are not posting the complete code. But in your case you just create an LinearLayout and set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. This is ok..
But in your  Linearlayout which contains the Recycler you are adding this  `android:layout_below="@+id/comments"`. Only that is not enough. You need to add the 
layout above attribute

```
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a paddingBottom on the LinearLayout that contains the Recycler with the same height that the Adapter in the Recycler

Comment: Yes but I don't want to make changes dynamically I think there is solution in axml level

Answer (score 0):

Change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout of which is below the recycler